# While rendering Image, 32GB RAM memory is used before blender crashes, 3.0 Ubuntu

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Before I hit render, I am comfortably using 3.4GiB/32GiB of memory just for Ubuntu, web browser and blender.  3.1/32GiB before I open blender and the scene I wish to render.  Below is a screenshot of my view port before render, because maybe you guys will notice something obvious about my setup.

[image]

I am rendering in cycles, @4k, with experimental options turned on (necessary because of the adaptive subdivision modifier), on the GPU.  When I hit render I get a the following memory utilization curve:
[image]

I may have a lot of vertices, but 32GB is a lot of memory to consume within a 30 second period.  Thanks for any input.  Any idea on how I can identify if this is a memory leak, or how I can reduce my memory use?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that de noising was really messing me up.  I set de noising to 0 (adaptive, based on anti-aliasing settings) and I was able to get memory consumption down.  I'm not sure why I got the double hump pattern.